# RXJS subscribe callback doesn't have access to current react state (functional component)

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I am using React with functional components in combination with `useState()` and RxJs.

I'm subscribing to a `BehaviorSubject` in my `useEffect[]` and everytime a new message is published, I want to check the current state of my component to decide which steps to take.

But: Even though in my program flow I can clearly see that my state has a certain value, the subscribe callback always only shows the initial empty value. When I stop execution in the middle of the callback, I can see that the "outdated" state is in the closure of the callback.

Why is this?

I've broken it down to those essential code parts:

```
function DesignView() {
   const [name, setName] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(name);     // <--- This always shows correctly, of course
   }, [name]);

   useEffect(() => {

      // even if this is the ONLY place I use setName() ... it doesn't work
      setName("Test Test Test Test");

      let subscription = directionService.getDirection().subscribe(() => {
         console.log(name);    // <--- this only ever shows "" and never "Test Test Test Test"
                               //      no matter at what point of time the published messages arrive!
      });

      return () => {
         subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
   }, []);

   return (
      ...
   );
}
```

Comment: I agree it won't change immediately... but it should show the current value once it changed, shouldn't it? So to be more exact: if the published value comes in after name changed, the subscribe callback should see it, right?

Comment: That sounds weird but it matches what I observe. Usual closures give the value of the enclosed variable when the function is called, not when it is created. What would be a possible solution? Create a ref for the state?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is that a non-react callback only ever sees a static copy of the state. The same problem appears in the useEffect cleanup function.

Solution:

Either

1. Add a ref to the state variable. Change the `ref.current` whenever the state changes and use the ref in the callback
2. Add the state variable to the dependency array of useEffect and unsubscribe/subscribe every time